# Build in qt with CMakeLists.txt Compile Output make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

Build with `CMakeLists.txt`, compile output is as follows:

> make: No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
>
> 20:28:38: The process "/usr/local/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 GCC
>   64bit) When executing step "Make"

The content of CMakeLists is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

file(GLOB SRCS *.c *.cpp *.cc *.h *.hpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

if(OpenCV_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
    add_definitions(${OpenCV_DEFINITIONS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
```

Comment: The content of CMakeLists is:
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)
file(GLOB SRCS *.c *.cpp *.cc *.h *.hpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
  add_definitions(${OpenCV_DEFINITIONS})
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)`

Comment: can you edit your question with the content instead of putting this in a comment?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to combine together since there's an error when I'm trying to combine them

Comment: and i figured out the problem , but i tried several times to post my answer, unfortunately failed. I didn't run cmake at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you figured out the answer by yourself.

By the way, you marked `OpenCV` as a required package, so it is useless to test `OpenCV_FOUND`: if it wasn't found, cmake would throw an error.

Collecting source files using `GLOB` is not recommended by the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html):

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

Unless your version of cmake is less than 2.8.11, you don't need to call `include_directories`, `link_directories`, nor `add_definitions`: the corresponding information are "embedded" in the [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html?highlight=imported%20target#imported-targets) represented by the variable `OpenCV_LIBS`. Your cmake should be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    # list your files here
)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```